# An event is interfering with Select2 plugin's ajax-retrieved results

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-select2

I'm using Igor Vaynberg's Select2 jQuery plugin with the [Infinite Scroll with Remote Data](http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/#infinite) option to make an autocomplete search box for my website. The AJAX is working great and the results are showing up, but they are unselectable -- the change event is never fired and when you click on a result, nothing happens.

There are also no errors showing up in the Chrome console, so I think it's not a syntax error, rather the plugin is mistaking it for a disabled select box. **EDIT:** having tried a separate on-click event for the result list which never got fired either, I'm now pretty sure there's something interfering with the events.

Here's my code currently,

```javascript
// Search
$("#site-search").select2({
    placeholder: "Search posts",
    minimumInputLength: 3,
    ajax: {
        url: "http://localhost/mysite/search",
        dataType: 'json',
        quietMillis: 500,
        data: function (term, page) {
            return {
                q: term,
                page_limit: 10,
                page: page // page number
            };
        },
        results: function (data, page) {
            var more = (page * 10) < data.length; // whether or not there are more results available

            // return the value of more to tell if more results can be loaded
            return {results: data, more: more};
        }
    },
    formatResult: function(post) {
        // return html markup for individual result item
        markup = '<img src="'+post.image+'" style="width:40%;float:left;margin-right:5px">';
        markup += '<p>'+post.title+'</p>';
        markup += '<div class="clearfix"></div>';
        return markup;
    },
    formatSelection: function(post) {
        // This shows up in the select box
        return post.title;
    },
    dropdownCssClass: "bigdrop" // apply css that makes the dropdown taller
}).on('change', function(e) {
    try {
        var slug = e.val.slug;
        window.location.href = "http://localhost/mysite/posts/"+slug;
    } catch(error) {
        console.log('Selected search result is invalid: ');
    }
});
```

The select box itself is just an input with type: hidden

```html
<input type="hidden" class="bigdrop" id="site-search" style="width:100%;height:auto">
```

Comment: I tried placing a console.log into the start of the change event, but it was never fired.

Comment: I tried your code on my local with twitter json api and it worked very well. Maybe, another event listener prevents running this change event listener. Can you show a working example on the internet with a sample of running ajax data?

Comment: @MuratÇorlu I've made it temporarily live at http://indiewebseries.com. It's the search bar at the top of the right sidebar.

Comment: @MuratÇorlu I think you might be right about another event listener somewhere. I've just tried to add a separate jquery onclick event to fire when a result is clicked, and it's not being fired either. Any idea how to find the interfering event?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Your problem seems like, your result data doesn't have a property named "id". [Select2 plugins wants an id field](https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2/blob/master/select2.js#L716) on data and if it has not, it makes option "unselectable". You may give an id function to override this behavior:

```
$("#site-search").select2({
   id: function(obj) {
      return obj.slug; // use slug field for id
   },
   ...
```

Comment: I'm checking this out now, I never saw this in the documentation anywhere!

Comment: That was it! Thank you very much for that. I'll award you the bounty in an hour when it lets me.

Comment: I found this via a google search for "select2 unselectable" and this absolutely was the fix for my issue...thanks Murat...