# Can't select item in list created by ui-select2

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui, jquery-select2

In my HTML I have this line:

```
<input  ng-change="privChanged()" ng-model="selectedPriv" ui-select2="privsSelect2options"></input>
```

and the `privsSelect2options` function:

```
$scope.privsSelect2options = {
    placeholder: "Wybierz privo",
    allowClear:true,
    minimumInputLength: function(){return  3;},
    formatInputTooShort: function (input, min) {return "Wprowadź conajmniej " + min + " znaki.";},
    formatSearching: function () { return "Wyszukiwanie..."; },
    formatNoMatches: function () { return "Nie znaleziono pasujących województw."; },
    query: function (query) {
       query.callback( {results: $filter('filter')($scope.privs,{name: query.term}) } );
    },
    formatResult: function(priv){
        return priv.name;
    },
    formatSelection: function(priv){
        return priv.name;
    }
};
```

Everything works OK when I put 3 letters it filters the result and shows it correct but I can't click and select any item from the result list. Can anyone help me in this matter? It doesn't even come into the `formatSelection` function.

Comment: Can you attach `privChanged()` function definition to the question.

Comment: yes, I attached it. the problem was sth else. I post in answer

Answer (score 20, accepted):

the problem was that `Priv` class/table didn't have id property, and its Primary Key was field code. I had to add function :

```
id : function(priv) {
        return priv.code;
     },
```

in `$scope.privNameSelect2options`

Comment: Can you give me a full example. I've this problem too.

Comment: Just add this function to $scope.privNameSelect2options and instead of 'code' put a name of a field which is identifier in your entity.

Answer (score 7):

Please refer to [Select2 Ajax Method Not Selecting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14819865/select2-ajax-method-not-selecting),

and take the correct value:

```
id: function(data){return {id: data.id};},
```

or

```
id: function(data){return data.id}
```

Answer (score 1):

Although this isn't really specified in the select2 documentation, you'll need to pass an id key with a function value to select2.

```
$scope.privsSelect2options = {
    id: function(element) { return element.name; }
    ...
};
```