# can't select json-results on select2

Tags: javascript, json, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4, select2-rails

having JS like:

```
$(".select2-input").select2({
        placeholder: placeholder,
        id: function(data){return data.id},
        ajax: {
            url: "/autocomplete",
            datatype: 'json',
            data: function (params) {
                return {
                    q: params.term, // search term
                    page: params.page
                };
            },
            results: function (data) {
                return {
                    results: data.results
                };
            },
            cache: true,
            id: function(connection){
                console.log(connection);
            }
        }
    });
```

and results from "/autocomplete" URL like this:

```
{"results":[{"id":14953,"text":"Dohn Doe"},{"id":15467,"text":"Jane Dohe"}]}
```

With all of this I can see autocomplete results, but clicking on any results causes no changes!

So I've been trying to implement answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15639184/cant-select-item-in-list-created-by-ui-select2), but with no luck. Probably I just missed/messed something.

Also this line

```
console.log(connection);
```

writes nothing to console.

Select2 version is 4.0

Comment: You shouldn't need to implement `id` since you have an id. Where do you define `placeholder`? Are there any errors in the JS console?

Comment: ```placeholder``` is defined above, let's say as ```placeholder = 'abc';```. And I don't have any JS errors here :(

Comment: If nothing else, `datatype` should be `dataType` (capital T). You shouldn't need `results` if your results are already called `results`.

Comment: Thanks Dave for your help, but it's still on the same point even with: `dataType` and `return data.results;`

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "clicking on any results causes no changes"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, seems like I found the problem. First of all need to say, that select2 from version 4.0 does not support `id` option I've concerned above. This is the extract from [documentation](https://select2.github.io/announcements-4.0.html) to prove it:

> Select2 no longer supports a custom id or text to be used, but provides integration points for converting incorrect data to the expected format.

So the problem was not in the code I've provided (except `dataType` type, thanks Dave Newton!), but in the code I didn't provide. So there I had

```
input :person, as: :text, input_html: { class: "select2-input", "data-placeholder" => person }
```

– notice the `as: :text` part

and once I've changed it to

```
input :person, as: :select, input_html: { class: "select2-input", "data-placeholder" => person }
```

everything worked like a charm! Still don't know what drives me to make it text typed instead of select.